# ASP.NET MVC and Web Farm Framework for IIS 7 Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, url-routing

I am trying to set up small web farm using "[Microsoft Web Farm Framework 2.0 Beta for IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/download/webfarmframework)"

Everything works fine, except for one problem -

My web application is written using ASP.NET MVC 2 and there is no references to ".aspx" files used. A typical url looks like:

> `http://192.168.2.35/Billing/Account/Create`

Howver when this url is processed by the web farm it is rewritten as:

> `http://192.168.2.35/Billing/Account/Create/default.aspx`

`/default.aspx` is being added to every url.

I can workaround this problem using URL Rewriting. But I think this is not a great solution.

Probably I missed something in Web Farm settings?

Comment: Are you using integrated mode? You should be.

Comment: Thank you, Craig. Yes, my web application uses .net 4.0 apppool in integrated mode and this is works fine. On the web farm host no web applications installed at all, so no apppool used. The problem is in the web farm host - exacly that host appends to my URLs "/default.aspx" and redirect http request to host with my web application installed. So, I think it doesn't matter classic or integrated mode I am using, because a problem occurs on the host which does not have any web applications.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have missed a step in configuration and are seeing an undesired effect.  You can see this without the framework when you dont setup MVC correctly.  Check out this link for general info: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/08/introducing-the-microsoft-web-farm-framework.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I was already read this general stuff.
I realized that this was a environment-specific problem.

Then I used another web farm all became works fine.
Thanks to everybody for answers.

Comment: Glad you got it to work.  I figured you had found the general stuff.  I posted that in hopes that you would see MVC is an accepted configuration and that it should just work correctly.  This seems to be a neat new feature.